# Twilio $_REQUEST['From'] equivalent for node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to use 'twilio' to grab the caller ID from an incoming phone call. I managed to do this easily in my call.php file using the following:

```
$callerId=($_REQUEST['From']);
```

I have now redirected my twilio phone number to access a different URL so that I can use it with node.js (ie call.php is now call.js). However, I cannot seem to request the ['From'] field in a similar manner as with the .php file.  Is this possible? What is the easiest way to grab a caller Id and store it in a variable using node.js?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Are you using express or connect? something with a body parser? if so, you're likely to find it in `req.body.From`

Comment: @David, is worth to note that `req.body` only includes POST data. If the data required by the OP is in the query string, then `req.query` should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not using express or connect and can't seem to get them going... What are my options?

Comment: Got it working with req.body.From--- Thanks

Comment: @JoeAustin sorry, I didnt see your questions until now, if you're not using express/connect you can use [`node-formiddable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable). I'm not sure if node.js has a native body parser or not, it's been awhile...

Comment: @gustavohenke well, if you're using express you can also use `req.param("paramName")` and if you're using `express.bodyParser()` it will fallback through `req.query`, `req.params` and `req.body` until it finds a value, cheers. oh, and PS - because it was `$_REQUEST` i assumed it was `POST` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's a full example of getting [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/docs?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) request parameters using Express.  Before running, make sure to install dependencies with `npm install twilio express`.  You might also benefit from reading [this blog post introducing the Twilio node.js module](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).

This code is an example of responding to an inbound phone call:

```
// Module dependencies
var twilio = require('twilio'),
    express = require('express');

// Create an Express webapp, and use a middleware 
// that parses incoming POST parameters
var app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Create a route that responds to a phone call by saying
// the caller's number
app.post('/call', function(request, response) {
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    twiml.say('Hello, you called from ' + request.param('From'));

    response.type('text/xml');
    response.send(twiml.toString());
});

// Start the app on port 3000
app.listen(3000);
```